# Permission error when trying to add or edit addresses (e.g. Customer Address)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to do some development to the LogisticsPostalAddress form that is used on forms where an address is modified/added. When trying to add an address (e.g. to an existing Customer) I get the error.

> You are not authorized to access table ‘Shipping carrier’ (ShipCarrierAddress). Contact your system administrator.

I have scoured the user permissions and cannot find a way to give permission to this table. I would think that adding an address is a basic function, so can not figure out why I can't.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out it was an issue with the installation of the lab.

Answer (score 1):

What role is your user assign to? Are you sure users in that role should be able to add addresses to the customer? If yes, here is how you can add permissions to the ShipCarrierAddress table:

1. With admin user, open development envionrment (Ctrl + Shift + W from
   running Ax, or run "ax32.exe -development" from command prompt)
2. In the AOT, go to Security > Roles. Find the role your user is assigned to.
3. Exapand the Role > Permissions > Table, add new table and set table name to ShipCarrierAddress and EffectiveAccess (in your case
   you want to insert, thus set to Create)
4. Save the role, and compile the role (not sure if compile is mandatory)
5. Start a new Ax instance with the user with limited permissions and verify you have access.